# SQLite database file is not being written to phone - Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I'm writing an app that requires a writable sqlite file to be in the app's documents directory. I have the following code which is called in my AppDelegate method `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method.

```
- (void)createEditableCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded {
    // First, test for existence.
    BOOL success;
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *writableDBPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"photos3.sqlite"];
    success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:writableDBPath];
    if (success)
    {
        NSLog(@"database exists");
        return;
    }
    // The writable database does not exist, so copy the default to the appropriate location.
    NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"photos3.sqlite"];
    success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:writableDBPath error:&error];
    if (!success) {
        NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to create writable database file with message '%@'.", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}
```

The file name and extension are correct; and have worked with previous versions of the database. The database is located within my project, but when I run the code, I get the following message:

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Failed to create writable database file with message 'The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 260.)'.'`

Googling this error code tells me that it is a "read error (no such file)." However, the file is clearly there in the project. Can anyone help me solve this problem?

Comment: Uninstall, clean, rebuild and run.

Comment: *"the file is clearly there in the project"*. But is it clearly there in the app bundle? Is it being included in a copy files phase so that it will be present in the app?

Comment: Cleaning and rebuilding didn't fix the problem; how do I check the app bundle/copy files phase?

Comment: I would suggest you log your two path variables and verify that they are correct.  And when the app is installed on the simulator you can go to Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator, find your app, and do "Show package contents" to see what's in the bundle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed by going to Project > Build Phases > Copy Bundle Resources and adding the sqlite file there. I thought it had already been added, but was mistaken.